# Android Studio cannot detect phone

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

When I tried to run the app, I don't see the phone listed on the connected devices list at all. I have connected the Samsung S3 GT-I9300, which is rooted using Kingo ROOT app downloaded from Google Play Store. I also have turned on developer options and the USB debugging. Still, nothing seems to work. I searched online and tried finding computer management to search for the phone listed under device manager. However, there's no mention of portable devices or other devices. Nevertheless, the phone is able to be charged. Is the problem caused by the USB cable? If so, which type of USB cable should I buy?

Comment: i think samsung devices requires Samsung Kies to be installed on computer to get recognized.

Comment: have you check anyother device on that cable?

Comment: can you show SDK of Android?

Comment: At the moment, I am using Android Studio to develop app. I tried using another cable and it works! I think the cable I am currently using is both data and charging cable, but the previous cable is for charging only,

Answer (score 0):

Try install ADB driver from [here](http://dl.adbdriver.com/upload/adbdriver.zip)
and you can read manual [here](http://dl.adbdriver.com/upload/adbdriver.zip)